# UserID in table is 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i have a user table in this table there is a column userid,name..

and there is another table which is leave in this columns are leaveid,leavetype,userid

when usersignup the his/her info is save in user table like this

userid username:
1 abc

userid is primary key
then when this same user upload documnet like

leaveid leavetype userid :
1         2         0

then i want userid in document like this
leaveid leavetype userid 
1         2         1

i try this code to save userid in session

```
int user_id;
if (Session["UserID"] != null)
{
    user_id =  Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"].ToString());

    if (users == 1)
    {
        //Session["UserID"] = aa.SignIn(txt_username.Value, txt_pass.Value);

        Session["Login2"] = txt_username.Value;

        Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

        Response.Redirect("AdminOp.aspx");

    }
}

else if (users == 2)
{
    //Session["UserID"] = aa.SignIn(txt_username.Value, txt_pass.Value);

    Session["Login2"] = txt_username.Value;

    Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

    Response.Redirect("leave.aspx");

}
```

but in leave table userid column show me 0

Comment: where do you set `Session["UserID"]`? please add a code for it

Comment: this is    int user_id;
          if (Session["UserID"] != null)
                {
               user_id =  Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"].ToString());

Comment: The above line is gettng the `Session["UserID"]`. asking about where do you `SET?`

Comment: Your nested IF statement is checking whether users == 1 but then for some reason you've got the else if statement outside the nested IF. Not sure if this is correct but it reads strangely.

Comment: @murali in funtion...


        }

Comment: cc.leave1(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]));